# Complex search pattern when building MEF DirectoryCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef

I am building a `DirectoryCatalog` of extension assemblies prior to `MEF` composition with a search pattern **Foo*.dll**. With our current assembly naming convention, this has worked fine until the recent introduction of a *Foo.Installer* assembly.

How can I modify the following snippet to include all *Foo.* assemblies except *Foo.Installer*?

```
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Foo*.dll"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately Regex patterns are not allowed on catalog

Comment: Looking through the MSDN documentation, I see no way to hand the catalog constructor a list of assemblies. There has to be an alternative here...

Comment: You can load individual assemblies iterating thru all dll's in the directory and using AssemblyCatalog to add them to the aggregate